# Problem with ENUM in eclipse

Tags: java, enums

I have the the following error in my eclipse IDE:

Cannot reference a field before it is defined

I try to use an enum variable and some of its values have the same name.

```
public enum Enun {
    A(STATIK);
    private static int STATIK = 1;

    private Enun(final int i) {
    }
}
```

Could anyone tell me how I can solve this problem please?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't extend anything else because enum extends something already (by specification) but you CAN implement with an enum! Try this

```
public interface EnunConstants {
    int STATIK = 1;
    int AWESOME = 2;
    int POSSUM = 3;

}

public enum Enum implements EnunConstants {
    A(STATIK),
    B(AWESOME),
    C(POSSUM);

    private int val;

    private Enun(final int i) { this.val = i; }
    public int getVal() { return val; }

}

public class Sergio {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Enun S = Enun.A;
        System.out.println(S.getVal());
        Enun P = Enun.C;
        System.out.println(P.getVal());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, you can't reference static members of the enum in the enum declaration. If you want to name these numbers, then you should make the STATIK a member of a nested static class:

```
A(Constants.STATIK);

private static class Constants {
    private static int STATIK = 1;
}

private Enun(final int i) {
}
```

Although I would question the need for this - the enum name should tell you all you need to know about those numbers, and you shouldn't need an aditional static declaration.

Comment: Or if there are more values like STATIK it might be another ENUM in hiding

Answer (score 1):

Try it the other way around:

```
public enum Enun {
    A(1);
    private static int STATIK = A.ordinal();

    private Enun(final int i) {
    }
}
```

This has the side-effect that now STATIK is not a compile-time-constant anymore, but there are little locations this matters (usage in switch statements - but there you should use your enum values).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass STATIK in constructor, If you want to achieve this use something like

```
public enum Enun {
    A(1);
    private int someInt;

    private Enun(final int i) {
        this.someInt = i;
    }
}
```

Remember enum is a singleton by default, so no need to use static for this int.